# Install puppet enterprise.30 and accessing the web portal

Tags: puppet

I am getting the following error after installing Puppet enterprise 3.0.
https://puppet.example.com:8140/

```
The environment must be purely alphanumeric, not ''
```

Is this normal and what I see is a message when I access the web interface?

Am I required to set up a node before I can see a web interface instead of the above message?

Comment: Apologize I did not realized that this message was not completed...

Answer (score 1):

That isn't an error message. A number of sites report this as being expected behaviour.

http://www.drivard.com/2011/12/install-your-puppetmaster-server-on-debian-squeeze-6-0/

> You will see the message: The environment must be purely alphanumeric,
>   not ” that confirms that your puppetmaster server is running.

Comment: Thanks, I see this message in the site, shouldn't I be able to see the console? Do I need to do something more like signing the certificate of a node before I am allowed to see the Puppet enterprise web console ? `You can also go at the address https://your_server_ipaddress:8140/
You will see the message: The environment must be purely alphanumeric, not ” that confirms that your puppetmaster server is running.`

Answer (score 0):

You just go to port 443 to get to the console.

`https://puppet.example.com`

That's it. And you log in with the email and password you specified during the install.